# Fixed size ConcurrentQueue get element at index

Tags: c#, concurrency, queue, thread-safety, concurrent-collections

I have found an old code which implement a thread safe queue.
and I tried to create a new implementation using ConcurrentQueue

**Old code**

```
public class BoundedQueue<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly Queue<T> _fixedSizeBuffer;
    private object _bufferLock;
    private int _limit;

    public BoundedQueue(int limit)
    {
        _fixedSizeBuffer = new Queue<T>();
        _limit = limit;
        _bufferLock = new object();

        for (int i = 0; i < _limit; i++)
        {
            _fixedSizeBuffer.Enqueue(null);
        }
    }

    public void AddElementToBuffer(T element)
    {
        lock (_bufferLock)
        {
            _fixedSizeBuffer.Enqueue(element);
            while (_fixedSizeBuffer.Count > _limit)
            {
                _fixedSizeBuffer.Dequeue();
            }
        }
    }

    public T GetElementAt(int index)
    {
        T element;
        lock (_bufferLock)
        {
            element = _fixedSizeBuffer.ElementAt(_limit - index - 1);
        }
        return element;
    }
}
```

My new code:

```
public class FixedSizeConcurrentQueue<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<T> _fixedSizeBuffer;
    private int _maxSize;
    public FixedSizeConcurrentQueue(int maxSize)
    {
        _maxSize = maxSize;
        for (int i = 0; i < _maxSize; i++)
        {
            _fixedSizeBuffer.Enqueue(null);
        }
    }

    public void AddElementToBuffer(T element)
    {
        _fixedSizeBuffer.Enqueue(element);
        while (_fixedSizeBuffer.Count > _maxSize)
        {
            T item;
            _fixedSizeBuffer.TryDequeue(out item);
        }
    }
    public T GetElementAt(int index)
    {
        var element = _fixedSizeBuffer.ElementAt(_maxSize - index - 1);
        return element;
    }
}
```

My question is about the `ElementAt()` function or should I better call it `TryGetElement()`.
 in the old code the code used a lock in order to sync the different threads.

 However in the new code I removed it since I know it is a bad practice to use lock when you have concurrent collection.

So if the index is not found because the queue is empty for example I would get an exception.

 So should I wrap it with try catch?
 please explain how you would do it.

Comment: I am curious how would you use the `BoundedQueue.GetElementAt` in a multithreaded environment. To me it looks like a nest of race conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `maxsize` variable is not synced across threads, so there's a threading issue there. Also, a `ConcurrentQueue` already has an `ElementAtOrDefault` function that will automatically return `null` if the index does not exist.

I would update to inherit from `ConcurrentQueue` itself instead.

```
public class FixedSizeConcurrentQueue<T> : ConcurrentQueue<T>
{
    public int MaxSize { get; }

    public FixedSizeConcurrentQueue(int maxSize)
    {
        MaxSize = maxSize;
    }

    public new void Enqueue(T obj)
    {
        base.Enqueue(obj);

        while (base.Count > MaxSize)
        {
            T outObj;
            base.TryDequeue(out outObj);
        }
    }

    public T GetElementAt(int index)
    {
        return base.ElementAtOrDefault(index);;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no need to lock when dequeuing there is a full post about that. But thanks for elementOrDefault I did know that one

Comment: @Gilad right, you do not have to lock when you dequeue, but you need to lock around 'Size', which is not thread safe.

Comment: So you can use Interlocked class for that no?

Comment: @Gilad yes you can. I updated the answer though to only use the lock on the Size get.

Comment: @d.moncada Why is there a lock in your getter at all?  It's a readonly struct...

Also not keen on the "new" method hiding.  If you do ConcurrentQueue<T> queue = new FixedSizeConcurrentQueue<T> your enqueue won't be called!

Comment: @DavidKiff yeah, you're right. using 'new' is a bit dangerous, and it will definitely hide the original method. OP could also 'wrap' the ConcurrentQueue as well. You know what, I agree, it's read only, there's no need for it as it will never change it's original value. updated!